# How to use my custom yaml tag in Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I've created a YAML parser in Python to decrypt values using [yaml tags](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#24-tags).

```yaml
password: !decrypt LS0tLS1CRUdJ...TiBQRS0tCg==
```

In my parser script, I can add a custom constructor to decrypt the values.

```py
def get_loader():
  loader = yaml.SafeLoader
  loader.add_constructor("!decrypt", decrypt_constructor)
  return loader

data = yaml.load(open(file, "rb"), Loader=get_loader())
```

When parsing the YAML file using Ansible, I get the following error:

```sh
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  could not determine a constructor for the tag '!decrypt'
```

How can I add a constructor to the YAML parser that is used by Ansible? I've seen these tags before, like `!vault` and `!unsafe`.

Comment: Can you use another character for instance `_` Exclamation mark `!` has a special tag meaning in [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#fnref:tag-uri)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add code to Ansible to teach it how to parse your custom YAML tags.

It looks like this sort of things lives in [lib/ansible/parsing/yaml](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/parsing/yaml/) in the Ansible repository.  For example, that's where you'll find support for `!vault` objects in `objects.py`:

```
class AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode(Sequence, AnsibleBaseYAMLObject):
    '''Unicode like object that is not evaluated (decrypted) until it needs to be'''
    __UNSAFE__ = True
    __ENCRYPTED__ = True
    yaml_tag = u'!vault'

[...]
```

You would end up maintaining your own custom version of Ansible.

Comment: I also found [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/parsing/yaml/constructor.py#L170), but I have no idea how I can add my tag without having to fork ansible. Perhaps there is no other way.